Qt Designer: нельзя изменить размеры
Проблема: программа Qt Designer не даёт менять изображение в меню настроек виджетов, что у Layout, что у других. Варианты: минимальный размер, максимальный, политика размеров всё деактивировано - ячейки не нажимаются, числа нельзя вписать. У Layout нельзя выбрать даже отступы, могу только изменить имя виджета и всё. Установлена последняя версия. В чём может быть проблема?


Uiol, вы забыли опубликовать модуль .ui, который демонстрирует проблему. И лучше расскажите что и куда вы хотите вставить.

А что публиковать? Я просто создаю любое новое окно и не могу в нём поменять значения: Geometry, minimum size, maximum size, а если Layout вставить, то в нём нельзя тоже никакие цифры поменять всё по 0 стоит, только мышкой растягивать, а я хочу конкретные цифры ввести.. можно изменить только имя. Файл .ui нет потому что не сохраняю, зачем сохранять не работающий макет
